# Como conseguir o DNS Primario e Secundario do Windows usando Python?

Tags: python

Meu programa em Python para funcionar precisa das seguintes informações da maquina:

```
DNS Primario.
DNS Secundário.
```

Como posso conseguir essas informações usando Python?

Comment: Você pode usar [wmi](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html) para buscar essa informações.

Comment: Como eu faço pra conseguir o DNS com esse wmi?

Comment: Dê uma olhada na resposta correta dessa thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904047/how-can-i-get-the-default-gateway-ip-with-python

Comment: Amigo, não é possível sequer encontrar a palavra DNS nessa resposta que você me recomendou.

Comment: @thegrapevine , nem pesquisar qual query o WMI fornece para buscar DNS?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se está em solo `windows` ou `linux`, mas já fiz utilizando o Windows, você pode executar um `ipconfig /all` utilizando `python` e pegar todas as informações de configurações da sua interface de rede:

```
import subprocess

ipconfig = subprocess.check_output(["ipconfig", "/all"])

DNS_ip = []


InDns=False

for line in ipconfig.split(b'\n'):
    if b"DNS" in line and b"Servidores" in line:
        DNS_ip.append(line.split(b' : ')[1].strip().decode('UTF-8'))
        InDns=True
    if b":" not in line and InDns:
        InDns=False
        DNS_ip.append(line.strip().decode('UTF-8'))



print(DNS_ip)
```

O exemplo acima retorna meus servidores DNS primário e secundário:

```
C:\Python33>python.exe achaDNS.py
['8.8.8.8.', '4.4.4.4']
```

Executado em Windows10 `PT-BR` se o Win estiver em Inglês é bem provável que você terá que trocar o IF "Servidores" por "Server",  estou utilizando Python versão 33, Se estiver em Linux ou MAC isso não vai funcionar ...

Comment: Caro Ederwander, seu código parece muito bom mesmo, eu só não entendi porque fez `b' : '` ao invés de `' : '` (o mesmo vale para `b"DNS"` e `b"Servidores"`), ali não tem caracteres para escapar, concorda que é redundância? Eu sei que em nada afeta, mas também não parece se fazer necessário. De resto para Windows Server (ou para desktop mesmo) em Portugues esta muito bom.

Comment: o `b` se faz necessário pois quando você executa `ipconfig = subprocess.check_output(["ipconfig", "/all"])`o retorno produz uma instância para o tipo byte, então eu estou comparando as strings utilizando o mesmo tipo, repara que no final eu converto a string para utf8 utilizando um `decode('UTF-8')`

Comment: Você tem toda razão caro eder, foi engano meu, nem me recordava disto, obrigado!